# How to access PostgreSQL database in Django application

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, postgresql

I have created a simple `Django` application which tries to access table named `fruits` present in `PostgreSQL` database and display its contents. I followed the official `Django` documentation and implemented below code as far as I understand. But below procedure is incomplete I believe as `fruits.objects.all()` is failing to fetch any data. I am missing something can anybody point it out any help would be appreciated.

**Table: fruits**

[image]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class fruits(models.Model):
    ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

**views.py**

```
from database.models import fruits

def index(request):
    data = fruits.objects.all()

    print(len(data))

    for item in data:
        print(item)
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<database_name>',
        'USER': '<user_name>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': '<host_name>',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Class names are by convention writen with capital letter and are singular nouns. Thus `class fruits` should become `class Fruit`. Class attributes are by convention written in `snake_case`, thus `id` instead of `ID`, `name` instead of `Name`. Check [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and follow coding convetions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Django will create new table `appname_modelname` for model. So in your case this queryset `fruits.objects.all()` fetch data from `app_fruits` table, not `fruits`. You can specify table name using [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#db-table) meta option. For example to link model `fruits` with existing table `fruits` add following `Meta` to the model:

```
class fruits(models.Model):
    ID = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fruits'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

**UPD**

Django expect `id` field to be primary key by default not `ID`, to change this add [`primary_key`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) option to `ID` field:

```
ID = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: I am getting this error now

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column fruits.id does not exist`

`LINE 1: SELECT "fruits"."id", "fruits"."Name" FROM "fruits"`

Comment: @OliviaBrown add primary_key=True to ID field: `ID = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)`.

Comment: I would strongly suggest against using `CharField` as **primary key**. It's a bad practice. Use rather [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

Comment: @cezar thanks I missed this part. In DB primary key is integer field. So it should be integer instead of char field in model also.

Comment: how can I access a table that wasn't made using model.Models, let's say I used the command line to make a table, and add items to that table.
how can I access those items?